# Yammer feed not rendering in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, yammer

When integrating the "Embed Feed" option as discussed here, it renders fine in Chrome and FF browsers but not in Internet Explorer. It throws me an error in the console "SCRIPT5007: Object.keys: argument is not an Object --> File: yam-platform-feed-f5d0f077918de53fb6f6.js, Line: 80, Column: 12967".

Since there are no custom modifications from my part, so thought to raise this problem in this forum to know if this is a known issue or something.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks